# Does readarray allow to specify line delimiter?

Tags: bash, array

In bash `read` builtin has `-d` for us to specify line delimiter other than newline

Does `readarray` provide some way to specify line delimiter?

- Is it correct that it has no an option for that purpose?
- Is there a shell default variable for that purpose, similar to `IFS` for field delimiter?

Thanks.

---

After I saw steeldriver's comment,

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ help readarray
readarray: readarray [-n count] [-O origin] [-s count] [-t] [-u fd] [-C callback] [-c quantum] [array]
    Read lines from a file into an array variable.

    A synonym for `mapfile'.
```

but later I discovered:

```
$ help mapfile
mapfile: mapfile [-d delim] [-n count] [-O origin] [-s count] [-t] [-u fd] [-C callback] [-c quantum] [array]
    Read lines from the standard input into an indexed array variable.

    Read lines from the standard input into the indexed array variable ARRAY, or
    from file descriptor FD if the -u option is supplied.  The variable MAPFILE
    is the default ARRAY.

    Options:
      -d delim  Use DELIM to terminate lines, instead of newline
...
```

Comment: It depends how recent a version of bash (it was introduced in 4.4 IIRC) - a simple perusal of the manpage should indicate whether yours does (`-d  delim`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since bash version 4.4, yes it does. From the release announcement [Bash-4.4 Release Available](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2016-09/msg00012.html):

> The most notable new features are mapfile's ability to use an arbitrary
>   record delimiter;

(`readarray` being a synonym for `mapfile`). The description in `man bash` is

```
          -d     The first character of delim is used  to  terminate  each
                 input line, rather than newline.
```

Comment: Thanks.  Does delimiter mean the same as a separator and thus is to be removed? I have a file whose content is `1 2 3`. and `readarray -d "2" myarr < f1`  and `echo "${myarr[0]}"` outputs `1 2` and `echo "${myarr[1]}"` outputs `3`.

Comment: @Tim you can add `-t` if you want to "Remove a trailing DELIM" - exactly as you would for the default (newline) delimiter

Comment: In `1 2 3`, `2` isn't trailing however. What does "trailing" mean?

Comment: @Tim To remove the trailing delimiter means to remove the delimiter from each element of the array.  In your case, that would result in the two elements `1` and `3` (the `1` would have a space after it and the `3` would be preceded by a space and probably followed by a newline).

Comment: @Kusalananda  Terminology question. Before and after splitting a string, Is "delimiter" included or excluded (i.e. removed)? Is "separator" included or excluded (i.e. removed)?

Comment: @Tim There is no mentioning of "separator". The delimiter (newline, or the character specified with `-d`) is _included_ in the data unless `-t` is also used. See also [When to use the terms "delimiter," "terminator," and "separator"](//stackoverflow.com/q/9118769)

Comment: @Kusalananda: Unless `NUL` delimiter (_usage_: `-d ''`), which then is not included - less or unless `-t` - as the line is terminated beforehand.