# Is a delimiter included in the field in front of it?

Tags: bash, array

If I am correct, in bash, `readarray`  uses some delimiter to separate the input into fields, and the delimiter defaults to a newline.

[Unlike a separator, a delimiter is included in the field in front of it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482358/does-readarray-allow-to-specify-line-delimiter#comment883171_482366) (if I specify `-t` to `readarray`, it will be a separator instead of a delimiter). To verify that, I have a file

```
$ cat f10
1
2
3
```

Why does the following show that a delimiter (newline) is not included in the field in front of it? Thanks.

```
$ readarray myarr < f10
$ printf "%s" ${myarr[1]}
2$ printf "%s" ${myarr[2]}
3$ printf "%s" ${myarr[0]}
1$
```

I have another file:

```
$ cat f1
1 2 3
```

does it show that when the delimiter is `2`, the delimiter is included in the field in front of it? Why are the spaces between 1 and 2 and between 2 and 3 removed?

```
$ readarray -d 2 myarr < f1
$ printf "%s" ${myarr[0]}
12$ printf "%s" ${myarr[1]}
3$
```

Comment: Quote your variable expansions! Try `printf '>>%s<<\n' "${myarr[@]}"`. In all cases in your question, you get the output that you are getting because you don't double quote the variable argument to `printf`.  Additionally, the first argument to `printf`, since it's always a static format string, can _always_ be single quoted (do this).

Answer (score 2):

`readarray`/`mapfile` leaves the terminator there The newline is there, but with the default value of `IFS`, the newline in `${myarr[0]}` gets lost in word splitting. Quote the variable expansion to prevent that.

```
$ cat f10
1
2
3
$ readarray myarr < f10

$ printf "%s" "${myarr[0]}"
1
$ printf "%q\n" "${myarr[0]}"
$'1\n'

$ IFS=
$ printf "%q\n" ${myarr[0]}
$'1\n'
```

> Unlike a separator, a delimiter is included in the field in front of it

I'm not so sure if that's such a commonly-accepted meaning? Even the SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118769/when-to-use-the-terms-delimiter-terminator-and-separator) linked to behind your link says that *"a delimiter goes between things"*. The [dictionary definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/delimiter) would imply the opposite:

> **delimiter**
>      1. That which delimits, that separates.
>     *A comma-delimited file has commas as the delimiter, separating each field of the file.*